# iOS Project Shows Red When Loading with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, project

I have an iOS project that I copied from another project and used the rename method to rename it.

If I leave the project open and close Xcode the next time I open Xcode it opens this project, but it is red and no files show up.

If I close the project (without closing Xcode) and then just open the project again using the recently used or directly, everything is fine.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to clean the project and delete derived data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.That did not work. Still shows red.